# How can I run React Native code in real iPhone, if I can not login Apple develop account?

Tags: xcode, react-native, testflight

I am a fresher in React native development

and I have a stupid question

How can I install app into real iphone

If I can not login to Apple develop account, but i can ask project owner to download and send me some file in bellow photo (certificate, profile, key,...)

Thanks, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/). Here is a good [walkthrough](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/walkthrough/) that will help you a lot. In addition, you should also have the idea about the [2 Expo Project Workflows](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow).

With Expo, sharing prototypes, for example, will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to build and run using [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev) instead of native method.

Start application:

`expo start`

[Document](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/)

From real Iphone, install Expo Go application and use it to run your build.